# How can I flatten heavy wall texture for wallpaper?

Tags: plaster

I'm trying to prepare a wall for wallpaper, so I want it to be as flat as possible. It started out as quite uneven, but with multiple passes of plaster and sanding it's gotten much better - however still not perfect. The wall is quite... lumpy. There are many valleys and hills. They are not huge - the variation in depth is maybe 2mm at most, and they are smooth and large. You can only see them when putting a lamp right next to the wall, but they are there.

Unfortunately this seems to be where my Sunday Warrior skills have come to a limit. The hills are too large to be sanded down (at least I didn't make any progress with a drywall sander) and I can't seem to fill the valleys either. I'm really not sure what to do now.

I myself have two ideas:

1. Screw it and just add the wallpaper anyway. Hopefully won't be noticeable.
2. Add plasterboard on top. However the room is quite small as it is and I don't want to sacrifice much space for this, so I was thinking maybe gluing the plasterboard (with the same plaster I've been using so far) instead of using a frame and screws?

Or maybe there is a third option? How do you smooth out a wall like that and make it perfectly flat?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Longer tools, and better technique.

You can get a 6 foot long (perhaps even longer) featheredge for spreading drywall compound. Not that it looks as if you've even used anything as big as a common 16-18" knife.

You can also use a long straightedge to identify the high points you need to scrape (not sand) down.

If you are using actual plaster, you might find drywall compound easier to work with. If you're using drywall compound, please don't call it plaster when asking for advice.

Comment: About the tools - I've used a 60  and a 65cm (that's about 23 and 25 inches) long... not sure what they're called. Anyways, the first one (shorter) looks like a putty knife just really wide. But it's also slightly flexible, so when I push hard on it and drag at a 45° angle it bends a bit and I'm actually making a pit. I tried the second (longer) one today - it's the biggest that the store had and it's a fair bit stiffer. It also looks different, but I don't know how to describe it. Still, I somehow couldn't fill the holes with it.

Comment: About the compound - this is actually a bit embarassing, but I'm pretty sure I bought the wrong one. It's called "Knauf Uniflott" and it's marketed as a gypsum-based compound for drywall seams. However it still it seems to be fit for the purpose (if maybe a bit of wasted money). It makes a very fine paste, so I think it should really give a smoother result?

Comment: Ahh, I found a picture of the other tool that I tried today. https://ksd-images.lt/display/aikido/cache/573644f1d0d3646af50ca68d8ccb27b8.jpeg I really did like it better, but, as I said - didn't really seem to have much of an effect.

Comment: What's the difference between "scraping" and "sanding"?

Comment: scraping uses an edged tool. Sanding uses sandpaper or a sanding screen. A smaller edged tool can more easily/quickly remove large amounts of high spots that you have identified. A longer edged tool can help to level the wall by only removing high spots. Sanding is comparatively slow, but you can also level somwhat if you use a long straight sanding block.

Comment: If you’re in North America, look for “topping compound”. It’s easier to sand than all purpose or any taping compound.

Comment: And this is personal opinion, but I think oversize taping knives might get in the way. I max out at 14”, which means I’m not dealing with too much mud at one time. Clearly, this is a learning process, and you’ll find a strategy you like.

Comment: I like to work from small to large knives. And if the knife is being deformed as described, the OP is pushing too hard on it.

Answer (score 1):

That wall is far too rough for wall paper.

Not to be rude, but if the pic shows the results after your work, you will need some professional help. You do not have the skills to make a smooth wall.

You can possibly add a layer of 1/4" drywall if you think you can tape and mud seams and make them smooth.

The other alternative is to call in a handyman or a plasterer to skim the wall and smooth it properly.

Hanging wall paper over that wall is just wasting wall paper and time.

Comment: I absolutely don't have the skills. That's why I'm here!  Maybe you can give me some pointers about the proper technique and tools?

Comment: Using compound to smooth a wall is more an art.  It's very difficult to show someone when they are present with you. Almost impossible through text.  Maybe watch a lot of videos. It also depends on how much time you have to get the project done.

Comment: I'm not in a hurry. This side project has been going on since winter already. Although I have a vacation now so not a bad time to push for finish. Ahh, alright. It seems like the drywall might be the way for me. I wonder if there are any courses I could take about this? I tried looking for them yesterday but could find none. This feels like it could be a useful life skill, and while I undoubtedly will never be at a professional level, a week or two of instructions could have tremendous improvements.

Comment: @Vilx-   I would check with your local education department and/or library.  It is more hands on learning than reading/watching.  Most youtube vids will be from people who practice a lot(years) before posting.  They usually do not show the blooper reel

Comment: I wouldn't call a "handyman" to do plaster work like this. If you're going to call someone, call someone expensive because he's got a lot of experience. Getting a smooth wall is as much art as skill and both take time & experience to develop.

Comment: One doesn't need to call a professional when skills can be _learned_. This is not a case where a person needs to give up.

Comment: @isherwood - Sure, but if something is so far beyond my skill level that it's hopeless to get the desired result - maybe hiring someone is an option too. Besides, my wife isn't going to wait for years either. :) Anyhow, there's one more idea that we will try - several vertical metal guides + 1m wide metal featheredge (thanks to this thread I learned about its existence and found it in my local hardware store). If that still doesn't give good enough results, then probably hire someone.

Answer (score 0):

I would sand down the worst of it (wear good PPE) and vacuum up the dust with a vacuum with a good filter .    Then get some topping compound and a very wide taping knife.  Slather it on, say the left side and work it up and down, always with a slightly more force on the right side so that you have virtually no force on the left side.  Then carry on adding mud and using the same technique on the next part.   It still might require some sanding, but after a couple of coats it be OK for wall  paper.  Technically what you are trying to do is create "smooth wall"  which is the most challenging drywall project.

Comment: ... and now we whistle and act as if it never happened...